# enlazar un iframe con un form HTML

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Estoy queriendo mostrar un sitio web dentro de un entrada en wordpress, la cual esta dentro de un iframe, la cual quiero que haga un form pero no se enlazarlos para que el form haga su funcion dentro del sitio web del iframe, miren mi codigo.

```html
<p>
    <iframe  style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; display: block;" name="webs" src="https://downace.com/login.html" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" marginheight="0" width="535" height="430"></iframe>
    <form method="post" action="https://downace.com/login.html" target="webs">
        <input id="username" class="uk-width-1-1" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" value="antoniovm99" >
        <input id="password" class="uk-width-1-1" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="********">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submitme">   
    </form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que te falta para que funcione es un [`input` de tipo `submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit):

```html
<form method="post" action="https://downace.com/login.html" target="webs">
  <input id="username" class="uk-width-1-1" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" value="antoniovm99" />
  <input id="password" class="uk-width-1-1" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="********">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submitme" />
  <!-- Este input es importante para disponer de un botón de envío -->
  <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />
</form>
<iframe style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; display: block;" name="webs"
  src="https://downace.com/login.html" frameborder="0" marginwidth="1" marginheight="0"
  width="535" height="430"></iframe>
```